Why doesn't the Coanda effect also pull air from inside the jet / streamline?
As explained nicely in this answer, the Coanda effect will make a streamline of air draw from the surrounding air outside of the streamline. This picture shows it nicely :

So my question is what stops the low pressure created or the 'cavity' from taking said fluid from the inside streamline?

I also can quote the answer I provided :

That fluid that is removed has to be replaced. It sucks in fluid laterally from farther away from the jet

(if that didn't make sense, the answer I linked should clear things up)
Why does it suck in laterally? Why doesn't it also pull fluid from inside the streamline? The force of pressure / a cavity needing to be filled doesn't just act in one direction.
("The streamline" meaning the jet as pictured above)

I get that this isn't directly related to aviation, but one of the topics that is considered on topic for this site is aerodynamics.
(Check here for confirmation.)
As the definition of aerodynamics is this :

the study of the properties of moving air and the interaction between the air and solid bodies moving through it.

I believe that this would be on topic here.

PS IMHO Coanda effect far better explains airfoil lift.

What is the difference between the "cavity" and "inside the streamline"?

@MichaelHall The cavity is where the fluid fills (outside of the streamline from the Coanda effect). The inside of the streamline doesn't experience the Coanda effect, so there is no cavity there.
